# How to set local variable in list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a method that takes a list and returns an object:

```
# input a list, returns an object
def map_to_obj(lst):
    a_list = f(lst)
    return a_list[0] if a_list else None
```

I want to get a list that contains all the mapped elements that aren't `None`.

Like this:

```
v_list = [v1, v2, v3, v4]

[map_to_obj(v) for v in v_list if map_to_obj(v)]
```

But it doesn't seem good to call the `map_to_obj` method twice in the list comprehension.

Is there a way to have local variables in list comprehensions so that it can have better performance?

Or does the compiler optimize it automatically?

Here is what I want:

```
(sml like)
[let mapped = map_to_obj(v) in for v in v_list if mapped end]
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Starting in `Python 3.8`, and the introduction of [assignment expressions (PEP 572)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) (`:=` operator), it's possible to use a local variable within a list comprehension in order to avoid calling the same function twice.

In our case, we can name the evaluation of `map_to_obj(v)` as a variable `o` while using the result of the expression to filter the list; and thus use `o` as the mapped value:

```
[o for v in [v1, v2, v3, v4] if (o := map_to_obj(v))]
```

Comment: This also has the benefit of not traversing the list twice.

Comment: @Alex You mean in contrast to [Lying Dog's answer](/a/26672589/4518341)? Cause comparing with other answers like [Vincent's](/a/52313972/4518341) and [Bruno's](/a/26672768/4518341), they don't traverse the list twice.

Comment: @wjandrea - yes, I meant in contrast to the (still) highest-voted answer. I wrote my comment back in January, before trending-sort rightly promoted this answer to first place.

Comment: This is truly amazing. Thx for this piece of information.

Comment: Attention with this! If for some reason, `map_to_obj(v)` were to assign the value `0` to `o`, that item would be omitted from the list. Instead, I suggest using `[o for v in [v1, v2, v3, v4] if (o := map_to_obj(v)) is not False]`
There you have it, zero assignment works. Jeez, that just took me way too long to figure out...

Answer (score 78):

Use nested list comprehension:

```
[x for x in [map_to_obj(v) for v in v_list] if x]
```

or better still, a list comprehension around a generator expression:

```
[x for x in (map_to_obj(v) for v in v_list) if x]
```

Comment: It is a fine answer, and of course it is the same as [behzad](http://stackoverflow.com/users/625914/behzad-nouri)'s one, with list comprehensions in place of `map` and `filter`... I' going to upvote as I liked how [Lying Dog](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4134826/lying-dog) translated `filter` in terms of l-c, but the OP may approve either one of those answers as both are fine, useful answers.

Comment: The inner comprehension should be a generator expression. No need to build the entire list and only then throw away the empty items to build yet another list.

Comment: @Lying Imho Tim's advice is sound and meaningful, please consider editing your answer to reflect his suggestion.

Comment: @gboffi I upvoted this one instead of behzad's because list comprehensions are typically faster than map/filter due to the call overhead of `lambda`

Comment: @cowbert: If a `lambda` (actually any Python implemented function that the comprehension could inline to avoid the call overhead) is involved, yes, the listcomp wins. `map`/`filter` can win if the callback function is a C built-in though, as they can push all the work to the C layer, bypassing bytecode interpreter overhead, which listcomps cannot avoid, as they're Python level functions, just with direct bytecode support for the append-to-list step.

Comment: Silly example: Changing behzad's answer to replace `lambda t: t is not None` with `None.__ne__`, while ever-so-slightly weird in how it works (it returns `False` for other `None`s, and `NotImplemented`, which happens to be truthy, for everything else), would improve the speed of that solution (in local tests, the `filter` work drops by nearly a factor of 2), though at the expense of comprehensibility.

Answer (score 11):

A variable assignment is just a singular binding:

```
[x   for v in l   for x in [v]]
```

This is a more general answer and also closer to what you proposed. 
So for your problem you can write:

```
[x   for v in v_list   for x in [map_to_obj(v)]   if x]
```

Comment: This differs from my answer only by using a 1-element list instead of a 1-element tuple, and I think tuple beats list when it doesn't need to be mutable. :-)

Comment: @Ovaflo IIRC, in CPython there's a special case so that the list literal here compiles as a tuple. It's a fixed length and it can't be mutated, so it makes sense. But if you do something like `[map_to_obj(v)] * n`, that of course creates a list.

Answer (score 7):

You can avoid re-calculation by using python built-in [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
list(filter(lambda t: t is not None, map(map_to_obj, v_list)))
```

Comment: Is there a one-iteration solution?

Comment: @HaoTan not in python 3; in python 3, `map` returns a map object not a list, and `filter` returns a filter object; so, this will _chain_ the functions without making intermediate lists.

Comment: Is it possible to use `reduce` to do the job?

Comment: @HaoTan: Why would you? `reduce` is for combining many things down to one thing, not for changing many things to many things. The work done by a paired `map` and `filter` (that is then `list`ified) is equivalent to that done by a listcomp that performs both filtering and mapping operations.

Comment: It's worth noting this is basically equivalent to [Lying Dog's answer](/a/26672589/4518341), just using a different style. In Python 3, it's like the generator expression solution and in Python 2 it's like the nested list comprehension.

Answer (score 5):

A local variable can be set within a comprehension by cheating a bit and using an extra 'for' which "iterates" through a 1-element tuple containing the desired value for the local variable. Here's a solution to the OP's problem using this approach:

```
[o for v in v_list for o in (map_to_obj(v),) if o]
```

Here, `o` is the local variable being set equal to `map_to_obj(v)` for each `v`.

In my tests this is slightly faster than Lying Dog's nested generator expression (and also faster than the OP's double-call to `map_to_obj(v)`, which, surprisingly, can be faster than the nested generator expression if the `map_to_obj` function isn't too slow).

Answer (score 3):

List comprehensions are fine for the simple cases, but sometimes a plain old `for` loop is the simplest solution:

```
other_list = []
for v in v_list:
    obj = map_to_obj(v)
    if obj:
        other_list.append(obj)
```

Now if you really want a list comp and dont want to build an tmp list, you can use the iterator versions of `filter` and `map`:

```
import itertools as it
result = list(it.ifilter(None, it.imap(map_to_obj, v_list)))
```

or more simply :

```
import itertools as it
result = filter(None, it.imap(map_to_obj, v_list)))
```

The iterator versions don't build a temporary list, they use lazy evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a way of using `reduce`:

```
def map_and_append(lst, v):
    mapped = map_to_obj(v)
    if mapped is not None:
        lst.append(mapped)
    return lst

reduce(map_and_append, v_list, [])
```

How about the performance of this?

Comment: You can use the `timeit` module to time the different solutions, but your above snippet is an arbitrarily overcomplexificated way to do a very simple thing - and I doubt it will be either faster or more space-efficient than the plain old for loop or the filter/imap solutions...

Comment: @Bruno I like your «overcomplexificated» !

Comment: If I look at the no itertools answers, performance notwithstanding, I dare say [Lying Dog's one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26672589/2749397) is the most expressive of the intent, and hence the most readable. And what about performance? well, I don't know how much cpu you spend in your `f(lst)` calls but removing the `None`s one way or another is unlikely to change the whole picture.

Comment: `reduce` really isn't called for here. It's use is for reducing a list of values to a single value (typically, a list of scalars to a single scalar), not transforming one list into another list.

Comment: Beware, this has the side-effect of modifying `lst`, which I would consider a bug, though it'd only crop up if you held another reference to it. You could fix it by avoiding `.append()` and instead doing `return lst+[mapped] if mapped is not None else lst`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found to do this, which is cryptic but succinct is like this:

```py
[f(y) for x in some_list()
      for y in [some_item(x)]  # wastefully making a singleton list
      if some_condition(y)]
```