# Can I use final value in if part of list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Let's say I have a list of numbers from 1 to 10. I want to know the squares of these numbers that are less than 1000 and I don't care about the actual numbers. This is a simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve and I wonder if single list comprehension can do that.

I can do it like this:

```py
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
squares_under_1000 = [n ** 2 for n in numbers if n ** 2 < 1000]
print(squares_under_1000) # Output: [1, 4, 27, 256]
```

The problem is that I need to use actual square computation twice - I need to repeat myself and in case that operation was slow, that's... slow.

I know I can also use `filter`:

```py
squares_under_1000 = list(filter(lambda sq: sq < 1000, [n ** 2 for n in numbers]))
```

But my point is not to do that another way, as I already know how. Instead: is it possible to use a list comprehension to compute a value and use that computed value in an `if` part of my comprehension?

Comment: FYI, `n ** n` is not a squaring operation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set local variable in list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672532/how-to-set-local-variable-in-list-comprehension)

Comment: @chepner you're right - it's `n^n`, my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was one of the rationales for adding the assignment expression in Python 3.8:

```
>>> [ n2 for n in numbers if (n2 := n ** n) < 1000 ]
[1, 4, 27, 256]
```

Comment: I think it's better to just link to [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672532/how-to-set-local-variable-in-list-comprehension) rather than duplicating the info in them.

Comment: Great to know that walrus finds its use in this case, thanks!

Comment: @chepner is it possible to move the calculation to the part before `for`? I'm getting syntax error, but it would feel more natural than clunking it in the `if` part :(

Comment: No; the filtering condition is evaluated before the value expression is. Something like `[ (p := n**n) for n in numbers if p < 1000]` fails because `p` isn't defined yet the first time `p < 1000` is evaluated.

Comment: (And no, you can't cheat with `p = 1; [(p := n**n) for n in numbers if p < 1000]` because then you are comparing the *previous* `n**n` before computing the new `n**n`; you'd get `[1, 4, 27, 256, 3125]` as the answer `4**4 < 1000` when considering `n == 5`.)

Answer (score 1):

Look it up. (In a dictionary.)

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
squares = {n: n**2 for n in numbers}
[v for v in squares.values() if v < 1000]
```

EDIT: One could just as well have created another list comprehension in the second line, and it would have suited your requirements. But in case you need the original number as well, a dictionary would be better.

P.S. You were raising n to itself in your original post.

Comment: Interesting idea to use a dictionary, however it looks a bit like an overkill. I prefer `filter` with `lambda` over this, as I can close it in a single expression.

Comment: Personal preference: it reads better than nested functions with a lambda to boot. :)

Comment: I agree that lambdas are not as readable as anonymous functions in some other languages. I wonder how about performance.

Comment: This incurs an O(n) space penalty, which isn't necessarily *bad*, but is something to be aware of.

Comment: Agreed. The OP seemed more concerned about time.

Answer (score 1):

Your post asks for squares of numbers less than 1000, but you are raising your numbers to themselves; that is, x**x == x^x. I am assuming that you want x^2 == x**2.

@chepner has a good answer for Python 3.8 and above. For below python 3.8 (or if you dislike walrus operators), nested list comprehension may be the ticket here:

```
numbers = list(range(1,11))
sq_und_1000 = [v for v in [n**2 for n in numbers] if v < 1000]
```

Comment: Interesting! Thanks.