# In python list comprehensions is there a way not to repeat work

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'm not sure this is needed, since the optimizer might take care of it but the question is about:

```
[ x.strip() for x in f.readlines() if x.strip() ]
```

both sides need the strip, (just 'if x' is not enough).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set local variable in list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672532/how-to-set-local-variable-in-list-comprehension)

Comment: All the answers are good. But i'm going to mark correct the one with the map because i prefer compatibility with older versions of python and i know it's not eager.

Comment: And yes, reading those answers, it looks like they can all be adapted to this situation, so i guess this could be marked a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using `map`:

```py
[ x for x in map(str.strip, f.readlines()) if x ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you use sufficiently high version of Python (3.8+) you can use assignment operator `:=`:

```py
lst = [" aa ", " bb "]

out = [v for x in lst if (v := x.strip())]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
['aa', 'bb']
```

Answer (score 1):

While the most general solution is probably the so-called walrus operator (`:=`), in this particular case you're probably better off using the standard library function `filter`.

Here's one of many possibilities.

```py
[*filter(None, (map(str.strip, f.readlines())))]
```

Specifying the predicate as `None` means that only truthy values are kept.