# split method in list comprehension and for loop difference

Tags: python

I wanted to loop over a list an split every three items into one final list i came up with followings :

list comprehension :

```
inputs = ["1, foo, bar", "2, tom, jerry"]
mylist= [[int(x), y.strip(), z.strip()] for s in inputs for x, y, z in [s.split(",")]]
```

and for loop :

```
inputs = ["1, foo, bar", "2, tom, jerry"]
final=[]
for input in inputs:
    x,y,z=input.split(',')
    final.append([int(x),y.strip(),z.strip()])
```

but in list comprehension method it was not unpacking into those three variables until i placed `[s.split(",")]` within bracket while in for loop method it is not needed .
Im curious to know why additional bracket is needed in list comprehension while it is not needed in for loop method ?

Comment: Your comprehension has two `for` loops inside of it and your second example only has one `for` loop. I'm not sure why you would *think* two loops would be the same as one loop.

Comment: Because you use two layers of for loop in list comprehension, but only one layer in regular for loop. The equivalent in list comprehension should be `[[int(x), y.strip(), z.strip()] for x, y, z in map(lambda input_: input_.split(','), inputs)]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that `x,y,z = input.split(',')` is an assignment whereas `for x, y, z in [s.split(",")]` iterates over a collection, just as it would do in regular nested loops. Without the `[...]` it tries to iterate over the collection returned by `s.split` and fails to unpack those strings into three variables.

This singleton list approach is actually a common way to [create temporary variables in a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26672532/1639625), although I'd suggest to `split(", ")` so you don't have to `strip` afterwards:

```
mylist= [[int(x), y, z] for s in inputs for x, y, z in [s.split(", ")]]
```

Alternatively, use a nested generator expression in the list comprehension:

```
mylist= [[int(x), y, z] for x, y, z in (s.split(", ") for s in inputs)]
```

The latter is probably the preferred variant, but may not be feasible in all situations.